# React: Difference between side effect in component's function vs effect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I'm trying to understand the practical difference between having a side effect in a component function, vs having it within an effect which has no dependency array passed in (and as such should fire on every render). From what I can observe, they both run at the same frequency. I realize that effects allow for cleanup at the proper time, but I'm simply curious about the scenario where cleanup is not a factor.

The following CodePen shows what I'm talking about.

https://codepen.io/benrhere/pen/GRyvXZZ

The important piece is:

```
function EffectVsFunctionQuestion() {
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);

  React.useEffect(()=>{
    console.log("incremented within hook")
  });
  console.log("incremented within component function")
...
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Side-effects issued from the `useEffect` hook have the benefit of being triggered ***at most*** once per render cycle. The render cycle here means the "commit phase" when React has computed the next view and commits it to the DOM.

This ***should not*** be confused with what React calls the "render phase" when it renders out the component (*and children and entire ReactTree*) to compute what changed and needs to be committed to the DOM.

[image]

The ***entire*** function body of a React function component ***is*** the "render" function. As you can see in the diagram, any unintentional side-effects in the `render` or body will occur during the "render phase" which can can be paused, aborted, or restarted (*i.e. run again*) by React. Note that the "render phase" is to be pure and free from side-effects.

The "commit phase" the component can work with the DOM and run side-effects.

> Why does this matter? How to tell the difference.?

React actually ships with a [`StrictMode` component](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html) that helps you detect unexpected side-effects.

[Detecting unexpected side effects](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#detecting-unexpected-side-effects)

> Strict mode can’t automatically detect side effects for you, but it
> can help you spot them by making them a little more deterministic.
> This is done by intentionally double-invoking the following functions:
>
> - Class component `constructor`, `render`, and `shouldComponentUpdate` methods
> - Class component static `getDerivedStateFromProps` method
> - ***Function component bodies***
> - State updater functions (the first argument to `setState`)
> - Functions passed to `useState`, `useMemo`, or `useReducer`

Here's an example sandbox demo that demonstrates the unexpected side effects.

[image: Edit react-difference-between-side-effect-in-components-function-vs-effect]

Note that the unexpected effect is doubled.

[image]

Code:

```
const externalValue1 = { count: 0 };
const externalValue2 = { count: 0 };

function EffectVsFunctionQuestion() {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState(0);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    externalValue1.count++;
    console.log("incremented within hook", externalValue1.count);
  });
  externalValue2.count++;
  console.log("incremented within component function", externalValue2.count);

  return (
    <button type="button" onClick={() => setState((c) => c + 1)}>
      Render
    </button>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering this. I have a doubt if we have effect in render phase _i.e_ add side effect in function body itself, what practical difference does it make if useEffect without any dependency array always run when render is called? Also what are the cases when render phase and commit phase will not be in sync apart from strict mode.

Comment: @SurajJain Read the *fine print* under "Render Phase": "...May be paused, aborted, or restarted". This means any unintentional side-effect in the component body might be called multiple times unexpectedly. The `useEffect` hook on the other hand is always called ***exactly once*** per render cycle in the "commit phase", i.e. 1 render cycle = 1 `useEffect` hook call. As for the your second question, I think the same text blurb above covers that, the "render phase" can occur an indeterminant number of times, but the commit phase occurs once when rendering to the DOM.

Comment: Thank you for answering so quick. :) So to summarize, suppose a component state changes, React renders the component again _i.e_ call the component function which in turn will call child component function and in end will give the final object describing the DOM, which will be diffed with what is current being displayed on the screen and react will make appropriate changes to Real DOM (known as commit phase). After the changes to Real DOM are performed then react will run all the use effects hook of the components depending on their dependencies array. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @SurajJain Yes, that is close enough. Yeah, it can be a little confusing. Just about ***all*** of the time when ***we*** discuss components rendering we are actually referring to the "commit phase" when the DOM is updated. Basically what we see rendering on the screen. In React though, the rendering occurs all in the "render phase" to compute the diffs.

Comment: @SurajJain Shoot, I just realized that I basically just restated almost exactly what I said in my answer. Either way, I hope it has cleared up things for you.

Comment: Thanks, yeah difference is clear now :). Also are there any practical use cases where we want to use useEffect, one can also have side effects in event handler as that also does not run in render phase. For initial rendering one has all the data that needs to be passed as props and therefore can perform side effect before calling ReactDOM.render. So are there any things for which we need to use useEffect and cannot be done in any other way while keeping render phase pure.

Answer (score 3):

Essentially the useEffect hook ensures that code will not run until the DOM is mounted/updated. If you run code outside of it, it can be called before the DOM renders, which could lead to issues. It won't block content from rendering, since it's called after render. It's the equivalent of several of the previous class based lifecycle methods (ComponentDidMount, etc.). [Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)